# Joomla INI translation

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, translation, ini

I need to translate in my ini file a word that has a "()" or an "/" sign but it seems to brake when I do it.

eg.

```
sometext(text)="otherLanguagetext(text)" <-- this causes an error in the ini file an brakes all translations.
sometext/text = "someOthertext/text" <-- Broken also
```

having spaces work correctly:

```
Some text="Some text1" <--Works
```

The fact is that the original language is database generated and doesn't have any translation tag or something like joomla translation tag.

I just type the word I want to translate in this way.
I searched for an ini editor that might fix this out automatically (e.g place '/' or something ) but I had no luck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example `key`'s are invalid. [`INI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) files [by definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) can not have any of these characters: `?{}|&~![()^"` in the keys.

> **Note:** There are reserved words which must not be used as keys for ini
>   files. These include: null, yes, no, true, false, on, off, none.
>   Values null, off, no and false result in "". Values on, yes and true
>   result in "1". Characters ?{}|&~![()^" must not be used anywhere in
>   the key and have a special meaning in the value.

*—  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php*

[Joomla language files also have their own specification](http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files), which if not followed will cause an error when Joomla loads and parses the language file.

In `INI` files and Joomla language files *the value* also has special interpretations for specific characters and requires escaping for the use of some characters like double quotes etc.

Finally, Joomla has [language overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Language_Overrides_in_Joomla) that allow the end user to override any string set by the core software or third party extensions which also affect the way keys are translated.

Comment: thank you i think i will place Tags instead of the original txt in order to translate it through ini file without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SOME_TEXT  = "otherLanguagetext(text)" 
SOME_OTHER_TEXT = "someOthertext/text"
```

Hope it works

Comment: The left side does not match with the word I need to replace as a result to not be recognized :/

Comment: Its veriable naming rule you can't use ( or / . try to use all caps  like SOME_OTHER_TEXT

Answer (score 0):

Try to use backslash before those symbols like this:

```
"otherLanguagetext\(text\)"
"someOthertext\/text"
```

P.S. you cannot use ANY special symbols in your constants! Try to name them something like this:

```
OTHER_LANGUAGE_TEXT
SOME_OTHER_TEXT
```

Comment: Where I can set those constants from? because the text is not static in the template, is always generated from database.

Comment: If text is dynamic, how will you add translations then? As it might be n values of strings?